# Can I be the main source of fund for a UK visitor visa as a student?

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am an Egyptian university student.
I would like to apply for a short-term UK visitor visa. I am a self-employed as a Freelancer-ebay seller-while being a student at the same time. My earnings from ebay is transferred to my back account every month. In most cases students mention in the visa application that their parents are the ones who are going to pay for their trip considering that they are a non-working students, but that wouldn’t be the case for me i will mention that i will fund my own trip myself. I won’t mention my parents as a source of fund in the application so i won’t attache any documents showing their financial situation with my application, I will just attach my own bank statement and paypal statement. Would that be accepted by the embassy to issue my visa? What are my chances?
For records I have 2 schengen visas before for Italy and Belgium I don’t know if they would help!

Comment: Yes there is no issue whatsoever in doing that. It reflects good on you. However we have no idea about whether they will issue a visa or not.

Comment: The UK will want to be sure that your funds have been legally obtained. I’m not sure that PayPal statements showing a variety of payments from multiple sources will be sufficient if the documents don’t show the reason for the payment. So I’d recommend providing a record of your eBay sales and your tax return as a self-employed person.